# Need to remove table from DOM, and place Body into a td and put table back into DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom-manipulation

Ok, if you go here:  http://devs.dream-portal.net/smf205/index.php?action=forum

You will notice a table element that contains (under the menu) a forum (board index) on the right and 2 blocks of content on the left.  All of this is within a table element with the class `dp_main` on the table element.  On the right is SMF content and here's where it gets tricky.  Ok, this `td` element has an id of `smf_col`  I need to take out ALL HTML from within the `#smf_col` td element and place it just before (or in the same spot in the DOM) the table element is.  Than I need to remove the table element `.dp_main` altogether from the DOM (and all of it's contents), than place all contents from within the `body` tag into the EMPTY `#smf_col` td element of the table, and than put that table into the `body` tag.

I can only do this in the body tag, so that's why the table needs to be removed from the DOM and placed back into it once the entire `body` contents gets placed into the td element with id = `smf_col`.

Using the following jQuery (a lot of manipulating here, because I can only do this in the `body` tag):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    var $smf_content = $("#smf_col").contents();
    $("#smf_col").empty();

    $($smf_content).insertBefore($(".dp_main"));

    var $dptable = $(".dp_main").contents();
    $(".dp_main").remove();

    var $body = $("body").contents();
    $("body").empty();
    $("body").html($dptable);
    $("#smf_col").html($body);
});

</script>
```

The page is here:  http://devs.dream-portal.net/smf205/index.php?action=forum

I will disable my code for now, since it doesn't work anyways, and leave it in it's original state so you can see exactly what I am talking about, before manipulating anything, this is what I have to work with.  Basically, this this is done properly, the 2 blocks on the left should be ALL the way to the left and the rest of the page should be on the right.

Final Result should look something like the image below:
[image]

Comment: You should start by getting rid of the jQuery loader. What’s wrong with just linking to it? Also, don’t use inline scripts; they can make debugging a lot harder. It seems like something worth ruling out here.

Comment: Looks like you've forgotten a `</script>` tag somewhere.

Comment: Ok, I updated the code, both in the question and on the webpage.  Problem still exists and it's the same error message...??

Comment: Make *all* your scripts external, put them all in one place, and don’t use CDATA or comments.

Comment: try removing the `<!-- // --><![CDATA[` and `// ]]` from the script `var oInfoCenterToggle = new smc_Toggle({`

Comment: OUCH I see a CDATA in the body... how can I remove this using jQuery?  Like I don't have control over what gets outputted originally, and I'm using a module to manipulate content within the body only...

Comment: @SolomonClosson: You can’t. *Get* control over the original output.

Comment: @ArunPJohny - Well, I managed to remove, both opening and closing CDATA, but error still persists... argg!

Comment: the error is not in that... it is in the jQuery code which is trying to replace the CDATA

Comment: So there is a bug with jQuery on this than?

Comment: what are you trying to do in that piece of code... line 175 onwards... if you remove that script block it works fine...

Comment: Ok, so I replaced `.html()` with `.contents()` and it seems to be working a little better now...  Can you post up the code you are referring to Arun?  And what to remove that makes it work fine?  Basically, what I am trying to do is to put the forum inside of the `dp_main` table.

Comment: what are you trying to do with that code?

Comment: I just replaced it with `jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
 var $dpPrev = $(".dp_main").prev();

 $("#smf_col").insertAfter($dpPrev);
});`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37294/discussion-between-arun-p-johny-and-solomon-closson)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37375/discussion-between-solomon-closson-and-arun-p-johny)

Comment: did you try the update

Comment: @ArunPJohny - What update?

Comment: @SolomonClosson in the chat....

Comment: @ArunPJohny I'm in the chat room right now, don't see any update...  Can you meet me in there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
var $dpmain = jQuery('.dp_main');
var $body = jQuery('body');
var $col = jQuery('#smf_col');

var $ct = jQuery('<div />').insertBefore($dpmain);
$body.append($dpmain);

$col.contents().appendTo($ct);
$body.contents().not($dpmain).appendTo($col)
```

Comment: Thanks this works perfectly now, still wondering on how it will affect themes that don't have a class of `navigate_section`